# Accessing MATLAB code through JavaScript GUI

Tags: javascript, matlab

Can I access MATLAB code through a JavaScript GUI? For example, if a user inputs some values and pushes the the plot button in a JavaScript GUI it should access the MATLAB code on the backend and give the required MATLAB plot.